# Ubuntu Serverに外部から接続できない

Tags: ubuntu, network

SVN用にUbuntu Serverをインストールしましたが、ルータ外部から接続できず困っています。
とりあえずSSH接続をしてみようとポートを開けたりしてみたものの、それ以前にping（グローバルIP指定）が通っていません。
接続は有線で、サーバからインターネットへの接続はできているのと、LAN内では相互に問題なく接続できています。
考えられる原因を教えていただきたいです。

★やったこと

・ping許可
ルータ設定でWAN側からのping要求を許可

・DHCP固定割当
ルータ設定でIPアドレス(192.168.10.10)とサーバのMACアドレスを指定

・ポートマッピング設定
ルータ設定で上記指定IPアドレス(192.168.10.10)のポート80と22を指定

・ファイアウォール設定
ufwでポート80と22を許可

バージョン
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: 問題を切り分けましょう。ルータからサーバにpingや80,22ぽーとにつなげるかどうか、外部マシンからルータにping、80，22ポートに繋がるかどうか

Comment: @atsushi ありがとうございます。ルータ・サーバ間は繋がっていると思われますが、外部からルータまでのpingおよびポートチェックに失敗している状態です。ルータはWF800HPを使用しており、「WAN側からのPING要求」以外にそれらしい設定も見当たらず行き詰まってしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

1. 外部つまりインターネット側からルータまでアクセスできること
2. 1.をクリアしている上で、**空いているポート**を使ってポートフォワードの設定ができていること

の2つをクリアする必要があります。

1.はISPとの兼ね合いなので答えられません。
2.はルータが設定画面用に80番ポートを使っている場合などで、そのままではサーバとうまく繋がりません。
sshも同様に20022ポートからサーバの22番ポートへのように空いているポートを使えばいいでしょう

Comment: ありがとうございます。2については認識していませんでした。しかし使っているルータには「ポートマッピング」の設定項目しかなく、ルータとサーバでポート番号を変えて割り当てることはできないようでした。1のインターネットからルータまでのアクセスがまだできていない状態なので、ルータのメーカーに問い合わせてみます。

Answer (score -2):

自分でよくミスしたことを話しますが、
自分はよくルーター（WiFi）内のネットワークでサーバーのインターネット上のポートを調べていました。

やるべきなのはスマホのWIFIをオフにして、SIMカードのネットワークでサーバーの状況をチェックすること。